# How can I draw tangent lines for 3 points on a graph of data sets?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to find the instantaneous velocity at 3 points on a position-time graph (0.6, 1.2, 1.8), which can be found using the slope of the tangent line at that point. Is there any way to mathematically find the slope of the tangent line (without calculus, grade 11) and then graph that on the position-time graph?

This is the code for the Position Time Graph:

````
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Position-Time Graph for the first set of data.},
    xlabel={Time},
    ylabel={Position},
    xmin=0, xmax=3.5,
    ymin=3, ymax=1973,
    xtick={0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5},
    ytick={80,200,400,700,1100,1600,2000},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[ 
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
]
coordinates { 
    (0, 3)
(0.1, 10)
(0.2, 22)
(0.3, 39)
(0.4, 58)
(0.5, 80)
(0.6, 106)
(0.7, 134)
(0.8, 165)
(0.9, 200)
(1, 236)
(1.1, 274)
(1.2, 315)
(1.3, 357)
(1.4, 401)
(1.5, 448)
(1.6, 498)
(1.7, 549)
(1.8, 603)
(1.9, 659)
(2, 718)
(2.1, 780)
(2.2, 845)
(2.3, 913)
(2.4, 984)
(2.5, 1058)
(2.6, 1136)
(2.7, 1217)
(2.8, 1303)
(2.9, 1392)
(3, 1483)
(3.1, 1577)
(3.2, 1672)
(3.3, 1770)
(3.4, 1870)
(3.5, 1973)
};

\legend{Measured Position at time}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}```
````